# Use Json file instead of the server respond and use it for filtering

Tags: php, android, json, filter

I have Json file in my assets folder. I am using AutoCompleteTextView to filter result that coming from remote server using php as Json. But i want to use my Json file instead of the server response Json.

This is my code.

```
private static final String url = AppConfig.URL_JSON_AVAILABLE_PRODUCTS;

     @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if ((constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0)) {
                        filterResults.values = locations;
                        filterResults.count = locations.size();
                    } else {
                        mResults = getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                        locations.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mResults.size(); i++) {
                            if (mResults.get(i).getMatName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                                //a  = new_suggestions.get(i).getMatNo();
                                locations.add(mResults.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = locations;
                        filterResults.count = locations.size();
                        //notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }


                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked cast")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        mResults = (List<Product>) results.values;
                        //setArrayList(mResults);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public List<Product> getParseJsonWCF(String sName) {

            List<Product> ListData = new ArrayList<Product>();

            try {
                String temp = sName.replace(" ", "%20");
                URL js = new URL( url + temp);
                URLConnection jc = js.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));
                String line = reader.readLine();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("feed");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject r = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ListData.add(new Product(r.getInt("matnum"), r.getString("matname"), r.getString("code"), r.getString("matgrp"), r.getString("mattype")));
                }

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ListData;

        }
```

I want to use my Json file's data to use instead of the url here. I don't know how to implement that and put it in to the url

Answer (score 2):

You can save your JsonResponse in a file as string when you get first time response from server like this

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("json.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

And same as you can read file content as string like this

```
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("json.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

and on getting string from reading file you can parse like this for example

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
}
```